# How to get rid of Dell bluetooth Media control bar?

Tags: windows-7, laptop, bluetooth, taskbar

[image]

In the image, if you look at the taskbar, you can see a bar with the Bluetooth icon on it and some media control buttons. I added this by mistake when I connected by phone to transfer a file and Dell popped up a dialog.

Cant find a way to get rid of it now :(

Right click does nothing, just shows the normal taskbar icon. Bluetooth settings shows the normal Windows Bluetooth settings dialog which does not have an option for this.

Any idea how I can remove this bar?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it

Right click on taskbar -> Properties -> Toolbars -> Uncheck "Bluetooth remote control"